# How to test if a a method of main class is called from its wrapper

Tags: python, mocking

So i have a python class say

```
class Nested(object):
    def method_test(self):
        #do_something
```

The above class is being maintained by some other group so i can't change it. Hence we have a wrapper around it such that

```
class NestedWrapper(object):
    self.nested = Nested()

    def call_nested(object):
        self.nested.method_test()
```

Now, I am writing test cases to test my `NestedWrapper`. How can i test that in one of my test, the underlying method of `Nested.method_test` is being called? Is it even possible?

I am using python `Mock` for testing.

**UPDATE** I guess I was implicitly implying that I want to do Unit Testing not a one off testing. Since most of the responses are suggesting me to use debugger, I just want to point out that I want it to be unit tested.

Comment: One way to do it is using debugger. use pdb and add breakpoint 'set_trace()' right before calling the nested method_test and then step into the method to see if it is getting called or not.

Comment: Is it a valid option to mock `Nested.method_test` and check if it was called?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just mock `Nested.method_test` and make sure it was called...

```
with mock.patch.object(Nested, 'method_test') as method_test_mock:
    nw = NestedWrapper()
    nw.call_nested()

method_test_mock.called  # Should be `True`
```

If using `unittest`, you could do something like `self.assertTrue(method_test_mock.called)`, or you could make a more detailed assertion by calling one of the [more specific assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with) on `Mock` objects.